# How run migrate in all schemas with Spring, Quarkus, Flyway, Hibernate, multitenancy?

Tags: spring, hibernate, multi-tenant, flyway, quarkus

Good morning, I'm trying to set up a QUARKUS project with flyway, hibernate, panache and multitenant.
But the script only runs once on the first schema, would anyone know how to run on the other schemas?

**application.yml**

```
 datasource:
   db-kind: postgres
   username: postgres
   password: 1234
   jdbc:
     url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
     driver: org.postgresql.Driver
 hibernate-orm:
   multitenant: SCHEMA
   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   log:
     sql: true
 flyway:
   migrate-at-start: true
   baseline-on-migrate: true
   baseline-version: 1.0.0
   create-schemas: true
   clean-at-start: true
   schemas: maripa, bicas, rhino
   locations: db/migration/maripa, db/migration/bicas, db/migration/rhino
```

**LOG**

```
    __  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2021-03-09 07:41:54,213 INFO  [io.qua.fly.FlywayProcessor] (build-13) Adding application migrations in path '/home/idd_acosta/freelas/rhino/rhino-api/target/classes/db/migration/maripa/' using protocol 'file'
2021-03-09 07:41:54,844 INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanProcessor] (build-8) Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
    - @Inject field br.com.rhino.user.mapper.RoleMapperImpl#permissionMapper,
    - @Inject field br.com.rhino.user.mapper.UserMapperImpl#roleMapper
2021-03-09 07:41:56,228 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.lic.VersionPrinter] (Quarkus Main Thread) Flyway Community Edition 7.5.2 by Redgate
2021-03-09 07:41:56,348 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.dat.bas.DatabaseType] (Quarkus Main Thread) Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres (PostgreSQL 13.1)
2021-03-09 07:41:56,380 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbClean] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully dropped pre-schema database level objects (execution time 00:00.001s)
2021-03-09 07:41:56,426 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbClean] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully dropped schema "maripa" (execution time 00:00.044s)
2021-03-09 07:41:56,428 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbClean] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully dropped schema " bicas" (execution time 00:00.001s)
2021-03-09 07:41:56,430 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbClean] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully dropped schema " rhino" (execution time 00:00.001s)
2021-03-09 07:41:56,430 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbClean] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully dropped post-schema database level objects (execution time 00:00.000s)
2021-03-09 07:41:56,432 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.lic.VersionPrinter] (Quarkus Main Thread) Flyway Community Edition 7.5.2 by Redgate
2021-03-09 07:41:56,437 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.dat.bas.Schema] (Quarkus Main Thread) Creating schema "maripa" ...
2021-03-09 07:41:56,439 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.dat.bas.Schema] (Quarkus Main Thread) Creating schema " bicas" ...
2021-03-09 07:41:56,439 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.dat.bas.Schema] (Quarkus Main Thread) Creating schema " rhino" ...
2021-03-09 07:41:56,443 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.sch.JdbcTableSchemaHistory] (Quarkus Main Thread) Creating Schema History table "maripa"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2021-03-09 07:41:56,487 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbMigrate] (Quarkus Main Thread) Current version of schema "maripa": null
2021-03-09 07:41:56,496 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbMigrate] (Quarkus Main Thread) Migrating schema "maripa" to version "1.0.1 - start structure maripa"
2021-03-09 07:41:56,555 INFO  [org.fly.cor.int.com.DbMigrate] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "maripa" (execution time 00:00.078
```

[my path scrpts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mueUc.png)

As you can see it ran only in the first schema. How to run on all three?

Obs.: Sorry by my english!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question but from [the Quarkus docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway#quarkus-flyway_quarkus.flyway.table) it looks like this is by design.

> The name of Flyway’s schema history table. By default (single-schema mode) the schema history table is placed in the default schema for the connection provided by the datasource. When the flyway.schemas property is set (multi-schema mode), the schema history table is placed in the first schema of the list.

I guess it only needs one schema table as all three 'tenants' should be kept to the same version?

Comment: Still, it should run migrations on all schemas.